# Accessing ENV variables in Rails-AngularJS (1.5) application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, environment-variables

Working on a Rails-AngularJS (1.5) application and I'm having trouble accessing my ENV variables in the JavaScript (services, console, etc.).

I'm using dotenv, placed my SECRET_KEY in a .env file, and added the following to the bottom of my body tags in my application's layout.html.erb:

`<script type="text/javascript">
   var SECRET_KEY =  "<% ENV['SECRET_KEY'].html_safe %>";
 </script>`

So grateful for any guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to do it in this way:

```
<%= content_tag "div", id: "secret_key", data: { key: ENV['SECRET_KEY'] } do %>
<% end %>
```

Add this to your layout.html.erb, so you can access the data from JS using:

```
var secret_key = document.getElementById("secret_key").dataset.key
```

Comment: Thanks, Pablo.  
  
Without jQuery, that last bit should be:  

var secret_key = document.getElementById("secret_key").dataset.key;  

Is there a way to hide the secret_key element from being seen in the html console? Even with "display:none" and "visibility:hidden" it's able to be read.

Comment: All the front end content is accessible from browser console. I recommend you to create secret keys related to the user, so if a user access to this data, that is not a problem,  cause it only will allow him/her to read or write content owned by him/herself